# What type of connector do pc fans use

Tags: connector

https://www.ebay.co.uk/p/3-Pack-PWM-Fan-Extension-Cable-4-Pin-Male-Plug-to-Female-Socket-30cm-Lead-006/1438200453?iid=191576633683

So I want to know the name of this connector?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a 0.1" pitch, molex wire to board connector, like [this](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0470541000_CRIMP_HOUSINGS.xml)